Excel VBA. Opening another workbook to update cell from current workbook value
I would like to update the cell value in another workbook from current workbook value ​​entered in cell which is 'cellval ' variable. Can you please check if there is a mistake of the code
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim adocn, sConnString, aa As String, cellval, cellval_row, col_row_number, target_col_number, targetCol, ptfile
 Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
'''''NOT COLUMN DATES
If Not InStr(1, Cells(1, Target.Column), "DATE", vbTextCompare) > 0 And Not Cells(1, Target.Column) = "SYS Payment Rcvd" And Cells(Target.row, 1) > 0 And Target.row > 1 And Not Cells(1, Target.Column) = "ROW NUMBER" Then
cellval = Cells(Target.row, Target.Column)
targetCol = Cells(1, Target.Column)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
 
  pop_up "updating record"
  
  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Posted Payments\" & "ptdata" & ".xlsx")
 
   col_row_number = wb2.Sheets("frmt").Rows(1).Find("ROW NUMBER").Column
    target_col_number = wb2.Sheets("frmt").Rows(1).Find(targetCol).Column
 
      Set cellval_row = wb2.Sheets("frmt").Columns(col_row_number).Find(What:=cellval, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
   
     wb2.Sheets("frmt").Cells(cellval_row, target_col_number) = cellval
    
pop_up "Finish Save"
 
  wb2.Close True
  

End Sub

Help is much appreciated. Thank you

cellval = Cells(Target.row, Target.Column) --> cellval = Target.Cells(1).Value

@BigBen Hi, still not working, the opened workbook cell from this wb2.Sheets("frmt").Cells(cellval_row, target_col_number) = cellval was not updating base on 'cellval' value

Do you have On Error Resume Next somewhere? You're also missing an End If in your posted code.

@BigBen No, the code I put there was the code I used now.

That code doesn't compile though, you're missing an End If.

@BigBen I already put End If in my code here but still doesn't work. The opened workbook base on the cell  wb2.Sheets("frmt").Cells(cellval_row, target_col_number) was not updating

Highly suggest you use Debug.Print or watches to debug further.

Side note: anytime you call .Find, you want to test if something was found

When you use .Find, you're setting a Range to cellval_row, but then use that as a numeric value in ).Cells(cellval_row, target_col_number).  You need to test if it is found, and if it is, use cellval_row.row perhaps..?

I see now. When I tried to Debug.print the cellval_row the result was the same value of cellval. Any reason please?

When working with multiple workbooks best practice is to assign each to a variable:
Dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as Workbook
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Posted Payments\" & "ptdata" & ".xlsx")

Then you can specify which workbook the changes should apply to:
wb2.Worksheets(1).Cells(cellval_row, target_col_number) = cellval


I fully agree that it's a good idea to use a variable to keep the reference to the opened workbook and to use variables instead of relying in the ActiveSheet. However, your statement "Workbooks.Open does open the workbook, but doesn't activate it" is not true - the opened workbook gets the ActiveWorkbook and the sheet that was active when the opened workbook was saved gets the Activesheet. And as BigBen already pointed out: You are confusing Workbook and Worksheet.

Hi, thank you for the replies. I updated the code now but still its not working the cell of opened workbook cell not changed wb2.Sheets("frmt").Cells(cellval_row, target_col_number) = cellval

I fixed my mistakes in the answer, thanks for pointing them out.
